# What makes a source script not loading and then loading again?

Tags: javascript, caching, src

When using a `<script>` tag with `src` attribute one should expect it to download:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/neovis.js@2.0.0-alpha.9/dist/neovis.js"></script>
```

However recently it fails to download, and I fail to locate the reason why it becomes so. The possibly reliable fix is that when that happens, I change it to:

```html
<script>
function cdnLoaded() {
    console.log('loaded');
}
function cdnError() {
    console.log('not loaded');
    // do error handling here
}
</script>    
<script onload="cdnLoaded()" onerror="cdnError()" async src="https://unpkg.com/neovis.js@2.0.0-alpha.9/dist/neovis.js"></script>
```

At this point, the console says it's loaded but actually it's not. But after that when I revert it back to:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/neovis.js@2.0.0-alpha.9/dist/neovis.js"></script>
```

then it works again. This has happened twice in two browsers (Edge and Firefox), and I haven't had a chance to test it again.

What can be the reason for this strange behavior? Could this be a kind of caching?

Comment: Perhaps this is a question for [unpkg.com](https://twitter.com/unpkg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser cache scripts by filename.
Probably adding/removing onload and onerror properties force the browser to download the script again.

To force file reload you could apply a versioning

```
<script src="util.js?v=1"></script>
```

Modern frameworks use to join, minify and rename script file automatically.
You can do it with tools like webpack

Comment: Why do applying a versioning make the file reload (if the file is already in that version)? In my case, isn't that it's already have a versioning (@2.0.0-alpha.9)? And if you can force reloading, does that mean caching has no effect?

Comment: more importantly, caching doesn't explain why the lib becomes not working when it worked before

Comment: When the lib is not working, what is the error? 

Also, with "versioning" I mean adding any variable that "changes" the filename, in the example above "?v=1". To update browser cache just update the version with "?v=2", "?v=3" and so on.